# Remove item inside spinner when spinner is clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner, coroutine

In `MainActivity`, it has a `spinner` where the item is get from server using `Coroutine`

**Code**

```
fun getList() {
        val service = RetrofitFactory.makeRetrofitService()
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val request = WebApi.getList(context)
            request?.userName.let {
                for (i in it!!.iterator()) {
                    list.put("", "")
                    list.put("None","None")
                    list[i.name!!] = i.id!!  // Ali
                }

                spinnerName?.let { spn ->
                    spn.adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.spinner_item, list.keys.toTypedArray())
                    val position = (spn.adapter as ArrayAdapter<String>).getPosition("")
                    spn.setSelection(position)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

At first, I want the spinner show `empty` as default. When user click the spinner, it will only shows **two items**, which are 'None' and 'Ali'.

How can I achieve that?

So far I able to set empty string as default, but when I click, there are 3 items in spinner, which are None,Ali and empty String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your `empty` as default but not in **dropdown list**, you can do is provide your adapter list that's containing your `empty` entity at the end but for **adapter count**, provide one count less in `getCount()` method. so that last entry would be ignored in dropdown list.

See how it can be done :

```
val list = arrayListOf("None","Ali","Empty") // You can provide any type of list here
val adapter = object : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, itemLayout, list) {
    //Override getCount method and we reduce one count less when list is there, so that last entry would be ignored in dropdown.
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        val count = super.getCount()
        return if (count > 0) count - 1 else count
    }
}
your_spinner.adapter = adapter
your_spinner.setSelection(list.size-1) // We make our last list item as default entry
```

**Edit for O.P.**:

```
spinnerName?.let { spn ->
    val adapterList = list.keys.toMutableList().apply { this.add("Empty") }
    spn.adapter = object : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_item, adapterList) {
        //Override getCount method and we reduce one count less when list is there, so that last entry would be ignored in dropdown.
        override fun getCount(): Int {
            val count = super.getCount()
            return if (count > 0) count - 1 else count
        }
    }
    spn.setSelection(adapterList.size - 1)
}
```

Comment: but how is my list is `hashmap`?

Comment: You've already used this syntax `list.keys.toTypedArray()` right? use like this : `list.keys.toMutableList().apply { 
            this.add("Empty")
        }`

Comment: how should I implement getCount method in my code ?

Comment: Are you adding empty string at the end of list?

Comment: @Hoo what was the issue then ?

Comment: oh no...crashed :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190853/discussion-between-hoo-and-jeel-vankhede).